# Java cd command going only foward throw folders, not back on input?

Tags: java

Beginner exam on building some kind of file manager (console app only), i'm stuck on CD command, this is that line of my code, any ideas? Thanks

```
public void cd(String arr[]) {

    File file = new File(currentFolder.getPath() + "\\" + arr[1]);
    if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory())
        currentFolder = file;
}
```

i'm calling this method in `Main` class and works only foward for example, first command `create Fruit`, there goes to `C:\\Fruit`, then l create folder `apple` in folder `Fruit` and l go to `apple` folder with `CD` command `C:\\Fruit\apple`, but l cant go back if l put `CD Fruit` to `C:\\Fruit` again? 
    I'm calling this `CD` and `Create` commands from switch in main method btw and works

Part from Main code:

```
    boolean run = true;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Application app = new Application(); // Application class where is cd method from above

    while (run) {
        System.out.println("Select the command:");
        System.out.println("CREATE,  LIST,  INFO,  COPY,  MOVE,  RENAME,  CD,  DELETE,  EXIT");
        System.out.println("Path: " + app.getCurrentFolder().getPath());
        String cmd = scan.nextLine();
        String arr[] = cmd.split(" ");
        switch (arr[0].toUpperCase()) { ....
```

Comment: What is your problem? Consider update your question and provide more details on the problem please.

Comment: read comment //i'm calling this method up....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.getParent()` or `File.getParentFile()`  to move up the hierarchy.

Assume you `currentFile` variable points to `c:/xxx`.

With `cd yyy` the currentFile should point to c:/xxx/yyy

With `cd ..` you could do something like this: `currentFile = currentFile.getParentFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly.

If you are in C:\Fruit and cd to apple, then the current folder is C:\Fruit\apple. If you do another cd command to Fruit, it is looking for C:\Fruit\apple\Fruit.

At the command prompt, to go up a folder, use .., so your command to your app should should be, not cd Fruit

```
cd ..
```

If you want to go up one and down another, you can descend the tree, too

```
cd ../banana
```

or on Windows

```
cd ..\banana
```

getPath and getCanonicalPath recognize the .. characters, so your code will work if you pass the correct parameter to the app.